# Visual studio setting or extension to highlight edited lines?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editing, syntax-highlighting, highlighting

I want to be able to see background highlighting on lines I have edited in Visual Studio 2010.

I know the thin strip next to the line numbers column shows edits in Green, but this isn't large enough/obvious enough.

Is there any setting or extension to help me out?

I want something like VS10x Method Block Highlighter that comes with the VS10x Code Map extension, but I was wondering if there were any options that are free or automatically highlight edited lines.